# Is it possible to integrate JQuery with Eclipse for Android applications?

Tags: android, jquery, xml, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

So I'm trying to make an android application very basic, it's my first actually but I didn't like the basic design so I was wondering can we integrate JQuery for the design of the buttons, spinners and the other controls. well I've been earching but all I can find is JQuery mobile for PhoneGap applications but I don"t have any html files only the XML files for the UI.

Comment: jQuery is Javascript extension. As I remember, there is no javascript support in Android applications ;)

Comment: Just found this here on SO. But have a look at [droidQuery](https://github.com/phil-brown/droidQuery). I don't think it includes the UI part of jQuery though.